# AutomaticUnits in WM10

Tags: units

Despite the unit improvement in WM10, I am still a big fan of the `AutomaticUnits` package, as I find it faster and more elegant to work with. However, it seems to be incompatible with WM10, at least when it comes to the declaration of new units using `DeclareUnit`. Does anyone have experience with `AutomaticUnits` in WM10 and maybe a fix for the `DeclareUnit` function?

Comment: I don't have version 10 installed on this computer, but in version 9 there are undocumented symbols `Internal\`DisableQuantityUnits` (a function) and `Internal\`$DisableQuantityUnits` (Boolean value) that allow one to disable the built-in unit support. This should allow the old package to work correctly (but, if other functions rely on the `QuantityUnits\`` package, they of course may not work correctly any more). Functions that certainly rely on it include (but are not necessarily limited to) those given in `QuantityUnits\`Private\`$QuantityUnitsAutoloads`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to disable the built-in unit support, as you suggest, but without any luck... The DeclareUnit function still comes with an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same issue. The solution I have found doesn't really fix `DeclareUnit` function, but allows you to pre-declare custom variables.

1. Create new blank package (File -> New -> Package).
2. Enter following code to create custom `UnitSet`

   ```
   UnitSet["Custom"]={
       DeclareUnit["CustomUnit1", Unit[1, "CustomUnit1"],
       UsageMessage->"This is your custom unit 1",
       TraditionalLabel->"cu1"]

       DeclareUnit["CustomUnit2", Unit[2, "CustomUnit1"],
       UsageMessage->"This is your custom unit 2",
       TraditionalLabel->"cu2"]
   };
   ```
3. Save file as "Custom" Wolfram Mathematica Package (*.m) in your `AutomaticUnits`package directory.
4. Open AutomaticUnits.m (located in your`AutomaticUnits` package folder).
5. Locate `Unit declarations` selection and under last `Get["..."];` add new line:

   ```
        Get["AutomaticUnits`Custom"];
   ```

   and save file.
6. Now custom units should be declared when you load `AutomaticUnits`.

Comment: That will do the job just as fine. Thank you for your answer, Max! Actually Jon McLoone replied on my mail and said that an update on the AutomaticUnit package will soon be available...

Comment: This may be pretty late, but have you heard anything on the updated AutomaticUnit package?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a really old question, but I think I found the problem. In the old Mathematica versions, you could extract rules from a Dispatch table using `First`, but in M10, you need to use `Normal`. So if you go into the AutomaticUnits.m file and find the DeclareUnit function, just replace all `First` with `Normal`.

The two places are:
`existingrules=First[$ToFundamental]` and `existingexactrules=Normal[$ExactUnitRules]`

You might also want to change the two `First` to `Normal` in `FastGroupDeclareUnit`, which is a function right below `DeclareUnit`

Hope this helps anyone who is still using this package!